# Install forticlient on alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, forticlient

How to install forticlient VPN on alpine linux?

If it's not possible, what is the smallest linux distro that I can install forticlient in? I will be using this as a docker image, hence trying to minimize the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightweight containers often use non-standard libraries and system setup so you cannot install on them software meant for more general-use distros. A plain Ubuntu Docker image is 64M, and, while being 12x bigger than Alpine, it is still fairly small. And considering that the Forticlient .deb itself is 64MB (and will likely expand to something bigger) the relative size difference of Alpine+Forticlient and Ubuntu+Forticlient is going to be somewhat less than 12X (and you could have to add a lot more stuff to Alpine to make Forticlient run).

Comment: Thanks. I will use Ubuntu then.